# Module B override module A

Tags: magento2

Recently I fixed a bug on module A which will keep update from vendor and I can't directly modify module A.

So I want to build a module B to override module A.

What files i want to override

```
/etc/di.xml (Modify) 
/Model/ResourceModel/Log/Grid/Collection.php (New create) 
/Model/ResourceModel/Log/Log.php (Modify) 
/view/adminhtml/ui_component/xxxxxxxx_listing.xml (Modify)
```

What is the best way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a module and inside the di.xml for it you can set `<preference for>` to override a class that is defined somewhere else. Like:

```
<preference for="Original\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Log\Log\Log" type="Your\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Log\Log" />
```

I believe any changes on di.xml should be able to override the di.xml on other modules when your module if loaded after the other module. Same with the `xxxxxxxx_listing.xml` , if you place it under the same path it is in the other module, it will go ahead and override.

Adding the original module as a dependency to yours would ensure that your module is loaded after. So your module.xml would have a similar part inside it:

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Original_ModuleName"/>
</sequence>
```

Hope this helps.